# Where to install XenCenter?

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, xen

I am new to the XenServer (and server virtualization as well).

I have setup successfully the XenCenter on my workstation and I can manage my hypervisors without any problems.

I have read in multiple places about a practice, where XenCenter should be installed in a separate VM inside a host machine. What arguments are behind that practice?

One of arguments that come to my mind, is that it simplifies connections with XenCenter. In case where I would be unable to use my workstation, I could use any computer with RDP software installed.

But what other arguments stand behind the practice? Why should I follow it?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice to install it on separate hardware, then XenServers it manages. Because if you do that on host it manages and it goes down you will have additional trouble salvaging your xencenter vm, before starting to work on host problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, that does not sound much convincing to me. Separate hardware can go down as well as the XenServer. XenServer can be accessed also over SSH and XenCenter installed on dekstop. My exact question is what other arguments stands behind installation of XenCenter on or outside XenServer.